# How to sandbox & codesign python application for OSX built with Esky?

Tags: macos, python-2.7

i've built python application then compiled with Esky for OSX.
then i want to submit it to apple store, i follow this tutorial http://dafoster.net/articles/2014/06/24/submitting-a-python-app-to-the-mac-app-store/

and check with RB Check and the result :
[the result of RB check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghuMc.png)

when i codesign one of 2 frameworks use system names but are NOT signed by Apple i get error:

```
/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how to codesign an app built with Esky (it's tough...). But to get rid of your error, you may be able to do something along the following lines:

```
codesign --deep --verbose -s "Developer ID Application: Your Name" .../Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4
ln -s .../Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4 .../Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
codesign --deep --verbose -s "Developer ID Application: Your Name" your-app.app
```

The idea is to codesign a specific version of the framework, creating a `Current` link that points to that version, and then codesigning the whole app.